# Replacing key from one dictionary with the key from another

Tags: dictionary, python-3.6, dictionary-comprehension

Suppose I have 2 dictionaries:

Dict #1:

```
statedict = {'Alaska': '02', 'Alabama': '01', 'Arkansas': '05', 'Arizona': '04', 'California':'06', 'Colorado': '08', 'Connecticut': '09','DistrictOfColumbia': '11', 'Delaware': '10', 'Florida': '12', 'Georgia': '13', 'Hawaii': '15', 'Iowa': '19', 'Idaho': '16', 'Illinois': '17', 'Indiana': '18', 'Kansas': '20', 'Kentucky': '21', 'Louisiana': '22', 'Massachusetts': '25', 'Maryland': '24', 'Maine': '23', 'Michigan': '26', 'Minnesota': '27', 'Missouri': '29', 'Mississippi': '28', 'Montana': '30', 'NorthCarolina': '37', 'NorthDakota': '38', 'Nebraska': '31', 'NewHampshire': '33', 'NewJersey': '34', 'NewMexico': '35', 'Nevada': '32', 'NewYork': '36', 'Ohio': '39', 'Oklahoma': '40', 'Oregon': '41', 'Pennsylvania': '42', 'PuertoRico': '72', 'RhodeIsland': '44', 'SouthCarolina': '45', 'SouthDakota': '46', 'Tennessee': '47', 'Texas': '48', 'Utah': '49', 'Virginia': '51', 'Vermont': '50', 'Washington': '53', 'Wisconsin': '55', 'WestVirginia': '54', 'Wyoming': '56'}
```

Dict #2:

```
master_dict = {'01': ['01034','01112'], '06': ['06245', '06025, ''06007'], '13': ['13145']}
```

*The actual `master_dict` is much longer.
Basically, I want to replace the 2-digit `keys` in `master_dict` with the long name keys in `statedict`. How do I do this? I am trying to use the following, but it doesn't quite work.

```
for k, v in master_dict.items():
    for state, fip in statedict.items():
        if k == fip:
        master_dict[k] = statedict[state]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to make a lookup table mapping values to keys. A second dictionary comprehension performs the lookups to replace numbers with words:

```
lookup = {v: k for k, v in statedict.items()}
result = {lookup[k]: v for k, v in master_dict.items()}
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'Alabama': ['01034', '01112'], 
 'California': ['06245', '06025, 06007'], 
 'Georgia': ['13145']}
```

Try it [here](https://repl.it/repls/RepulsiveSmugBookmark)